# How to create DOM elements in JS memory-efficiently?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, microsoft-edge, chromium, v8

Consider the following code that inserts 100,000 spans with the content '0' inside.

```
<body>
    <script type="module">
        const container = document.getElementById('root')
        const CHILDREN_COUNT = 100000;

        for (let i = 0; i < CHILDREN_COUNT; i++) {
            const newChild = document.createElement("span");
            newChild.innerHTML = '0'
            container.appendChild(newChild)
        }
    </script>

    <div id="root" style="overflow-wrap: break-word">
    </div>
</body>
```

In my mind, after each loop, the garbage collection should clean up `newChild` as there are no further references to this var. The `container` itself I assume is a pointer to the DOM element, instead of being the entire thing in memory, and either way, should be cleaned after the loop executes.

However, testing reveals this page will take up 200,000kb~ of memory (per task manager in Chromium), but if `CHILDREN_COUNT` is reduced to 10, it takes up only c. 30,000kb~ of memory. Could the difference be entirely down to the DOM having to hold more `span` elements? Since the content for each span is minimal, I would have assumed not.

Is there something that I could do here to better manage memory use?

Comment: What appens of you don't append the elements to the DOM? (I would guess you can't optimize here.) (You could also make a large string with all the spans and set that as innerhtml to root and check if it consumes less memeory this way.)

Comment: I have tried also to just add the whole thing as a long string as innerHTML just now and seems to have comparable memory usage. Perhaps it really is just the DOM holding all these elements in the end and not JS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check DocumentFragment -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment

```
 var list = document.querySelector('#list')
const CHILDREN_COUNT = 100000;
var fragment = new DocumentFragment();

        for (let i = 0; i < CHILDREN_COUNT; i++) {
          var spanEl = document.createElement('span');
          spanEl.innerHTML ='0';
          fragment.appendChild(spanEl);
        }
 
list.appendChild(fragment);
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks - where do you get the screen for your screenshot? JS Profiler?

Comment: browser - memory

Comment: Confirmed that without using fragment JS heap size is roughly similar. So seems like this is a browser DOM issue.

Comment: for 10,000 you are right, but for more, for example 100,000 with a fragment takes about 3mb, and without it about 30mb